# Padrões para desenvolvimento Android

Tags: android, conversão, convenções-de-nome

Alguém sabe onde encontro os padrões para desenvolvimento Android?
Desde:

- Nome de Views
- Nome de Classes
- Activities
- Resources

Comment: veja se isso te ajuda.. [Nomenclatura Android](http://blog.ceduliocezar.com.br/padrao-nomenclatura-android-como-atribuir-ids-as-suas-views-no-android/)

Comment: Acho que essas duas páginas vão te ajudar: https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html e http://petrnohejl.github.io/Android-Cheatsheet-For-Graphic-Designers/#naming-conventions. Apesar de serem padrões para o AOSP (primeira) devem servir de V0

Answer (score 2):

Não existe um artigo do Google dizendo como você deve renomear seus arquivos de Resources.

Como no comentário do @Wakim, existe um artigo de recomendações de código Java apenas.

Você pode seguir as boas dicas de patterns contidas neste blog:  http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/archives/

Respondendo sua pergunta, eu sou desenvolvedor Android há 4 anos e de um tempo para cá, eu sigo o seguinte padrão:

- **View**:  Se for como classe, cloque de quem herda primeiro, depois o nome do que faz.
  Por exemplo, você fez um EdiText que quando clicado, abre um DatePickerDialog, então um nome para seu EditText customizado poderia ser **EditTextDatePicker**.

  Para nome de classes, isso é muito relativo...

Se sua classe for uma Activity, sempre termine o nome dela com Activity, como o Google faz.

Por exemplo:  **CadastroActivity**, **ListagemCadastrosActivity** ...

Geralmente, eu coloco o nome da classe começando com o que ela faz depois o nome de quem ela herda, se herdar de classes do Android (exceto para o caso de Widgets/Views).

Por exemplo, se sua classe responsável pelo encapsulamento de um procedimento de listagem herdar de AsyncTask, você pode nomeá-la como ListarCadastrosAsyncTask.

Se sua classe for uma classe utilitária, pode ter como sufixo a palavra **Util**.

Para os Resources, você deve pensar na utilização deles via código, ou seja, prefixos que o auxilie na hora de utilizar via código para simplificar a sugestão dada pela IDE quando estiver digitando.

Ou seja, para ícones, você sempre deve começar com o prefixo **ic_**

Depois, você coloca outra palavra referente ao tipo desse ícone.

Por exemplo, se esse ícone é um ícone de menu que aparece na ActionBar ou em outro menu, a próxima palavra será **action**.

Então ficaria:  **ic_action_**.

Depois, você coloca o que ele faz:   **ic_action_cadastrar**

Se o seu ícone for ícones próprios de alguma tela por exemplo (só como exemplo)

Você pode chamar de ic_cadastro_activity_pessoa.

Para arquivos Drawble por exemplo, você pode colocar como prefixo o nome da TAG de nível mais alto, pois por ela é possível saber o que aquele arquivo faz.

Por exemplo, se um arquivo drawable começar com o prefixo **shape_**, você sabe que ele é para background, para colorir e configurar espaçamento numa View por exemplo.

Se seu arquivo começar com **selector** ou **layer_list** você sabe que servirá como sinalização de toque em alguma view e por aí vai.

Aí vem a regra que eu disse lá em cima, sobre a forma como noema para facilitar a utilização via código.

Isso por que para todos os ícones que você for buscar via código para essa tela, basta você digitar o prefixo: ic_cadastro_activity_ e várias sugestões serão exibidas apenas para esse prefixo.

Essa questão de ícones exclusivos para telas raramente ocorre e a explicação acima foi apenas para que entendesse a facilidade em escolher bem os prefixos.

Acredito que esse padrão desejado é você que cria, pois a comunidade ainda não definiu bem isso e seguimos exemplos do Google. Mas pense sempre na melhor forma de organização para você.

Forma essa que deve lhe auxiliar a medida que seu projeto cresce, como organização das classes nos pacotes, a própria nomenclatura de seus arquivos, tudo que possa facilitar a utilização.

Pense bastante nessa questão de trabalhar junto com a funcionalidade de sugestão das IDEs, pois a nomenclatura ajuda nisso.